# How do I programmatically Unblock (IE feature) a file?

Tags: powershell, cmd, wsh, windows-security

I like this feature, but in the current build of Windows, clicking the 'Unblock' button and clicking 'Apply' does absolutely nothing. This can cause issues - some files won't run properly.

[image]

That being said, I've not been able to find a workaround for this. But I believe that there is a cmd command to unblock a file.

How can I unblock a file using a batch script, or wsh (jscript or vbscript) or even with a Powershell script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PowerShell:

```powershell
Remove-Item 'C:\Users\Jase\Downloads\script56.chm' -Stream Zone.Identifier
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're using PowerShell 3.0 or higher (and you should be), use the [`Unblock-File`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849924(v=wps.620).aspx) cmdlet.